# a further investigation on an EGMO problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I was solving  EGMO 2018 problem 2 https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1625301p10185417.

And while finding the construction i kind of created this other question which i am having a hard time making any progress in .

Given the set $A=\{1+\frac{1}{k},k \in \mathbb{N}\}$

we call a non empty finite subset $K$ with repetition allowed of $A$ "primitive" if there does not exist a non empty finite subset $U$ with repetition allowed of $A$ such that that the product of elements of $U$ is same as that of $K$ and that product is an integer and $|U|<|K|$

How can we find all integers $u$ such that there exist a primitive subset of $A$ having $1+\frac{1}{u}$ has one of its elements. For example I think by checking $5$ doesn't have this property and when solving the problem i realized $2,4,8,....$ all have this property.

If the number is $2^k$.

Consider
$(1+1)....(1+1)(1+\frac{1}{2^k})=2^k+1$ [ k (1+1)'s]

We can show there doesn't exist U by contradition as all elements of $A$ are atmost $2$ so $2^{|U|} \geq 2^{k}+1$ so $|U| > k$ .

Comment: Can you elaborate on why 5 doesn't have this property?

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry i made a mistake in the post in that part

Comment: Also i am saying for 5 just by checking without a proof.Updated